# Why does unsigned variable contain wrong value

Tags: c++, unsigned

I am attempting to grab ID's from an text file with HTML in it. The ID's are being extracted from URL's in the HTML so I'm looping through the file to find the correct line and then using substrings obtain the correct information. There are two different types of ID so I have two different functions.

The second one (getYearId) works fine, but the first one causes the code to abort on the part that is currently commented out. As you can see, I've tried to output the value of `first1` only to find that it's output is `alue="`, which is part of what I'd assume `first` was supposed to equal. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

void getSyllabiId() {
string line;
ifstream myfile("syllabi.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        if (line.find("View Assignments") != string::npos) {
            string startDel = "syllabusid";
            string endDel = "View";
            unsigned int first1 = line.find(startDel);
            unsigned int last1 = line.find(endDel);

            cout << first1 + "\n";

            //string syllabusID = line.substr(first1, last1 - first1);
            //syllabusID = syllabusID.substr(startDel.size());
            // cout << syllabusID + "\n";

        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file.";
}

void getYearId() {
string line;
ifstream myfile("syllabi.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        if (line.find("2014-2015</option>") != string::npos) {
            string startDel = "value=\"";
            string endDel = "\" selected";
            unsigned int first = line.find(startDel);
            unsigned int last = line.find(endDel);
            string yearID = line.substr(first, last - first);
            yearID = yearID.substr(startDel.size());
            cout << yearID + "\n";
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
}

int main () {

getYearId();
getSyllabiId();

string x;
cin >> x;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: unsigned int first1 is declared and defined twice..

Comment: `first1 + "\n"` is a problem: you can't concatenate an int with a string in C++ with the `+` operator. Try this: `cout << first1 << endl;`

Comment: how comes this didnt pop compiler error

Comment: The double first1 is actually an error I just made and forgot to remove, the problem still persists without the double first1. But I'll try your solution @RPGillespie.

Comment: You don't check the results of `find` to determine if the search criteria were even found.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to figure it out based off of RPGillespie's and Captain Obvlious comments. Sorry for the bad question, I'm new to C++ and can't see an obvious error when there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I never checked to see if `first1` and `last1` had values, so obviously in one (or several instances) one of them didn't causing the code to abort.

Comment: If it's solution, mark it as accepted as soon as possible.

Comment: It says I have to wait two days.